# Problema con el background en matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.7, jupyter

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, figsize=(12,4))

ax1.plot(data_preciosReales['NT300-Ternero: <160_real'], label='NT-Ternero <160')
ax1.plot(data_preciosReales['NT300-Ternero:200-230_real'], label='NT-Ternero 200-230')
ax1.plot(data_preciosReales['NT300-Ternero:230-260_real'], label='NT-Ternero 230-260')
ax1.set_title('Relación Novillo (<300kg) y Terneros')


ax2.plot(data_preciosReales['NT300-Maíz ($/tn)_real'], label = 'NT-Maiz')
ax2.plot(data_preciosReales['NT300-Soja ($/tn)_real'], label='NT-Soja')
ax2.set_title('Relación Novillo (<300kg) y Maiz')



ax = (ax1, ax2)

for axes in ax:
    axes.grid(False)
    axes.legend()
    axes.legend()
    axes.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90) #Roto los ejes
    axes.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
    axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))

plt.style.use('seaborn-talk')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Relacion insumo-producto2.jpg', dpi=300) #bbox_inches ='tight' ajusta el cuadro a la imagen
plt.show()
```

Que produce el siguiente gráfico en jupyter:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando miro el archivo `.png` el gráfico se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? ¿Hay algo mal en mi código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema probablemente viene del diseño que introduces mediante `plt.style.use('seaborn-talk')`, si quieres cambiar el fondo tienes dos opciones

1. Utilizar otro estilo que no sea `seaborn-talk`
2. Cambiar el background después del estilo:

Para cambiarlo puedes introducir la siguiente linea de código: `fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada siempre es un placer ayudar. Como eres nuevo posiblemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick "aceptar respuesta", y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recompensará a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia) :)